# silent post url is not getting the response in authorize.net simple checkout

Tags: asp.net, authorize.net

I have been using Authorize.Net payment gateway in my asp.net application.
I have generated the donate button along with key from authorize.net account. And also I included the **silent post url** in the account. When I click the donate button it redirects to the site and payment is works well. But I didn't get the any response from authorize.net.
Anyone please help me , thanks in advance

Comment: If you can't obtain support directly from the vendor, you have to include references and/or code so _this_ community can even begin to try and help you...

Comment: I am having only the donate button containing the API key and action to checkout page.

Comment: A common problem with silent post is when it's not a publicly addressable URL or has firewall rules that block access.